# Can't see usage of Azure CDN

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-cdn, microsoft-cdn

I have an Azure CDN setup to an Origin WebApp, and I've edited my custom domain's DNS records so that the root site now points to the Azure CDN instead of the WebApp.

Now I just want to double check that everything is being routed correctly, and that the CDN is functioning properly, but I can't see any usage data for the Azure CDN.

I've found some older questions that tell to look on the CDN Profile and then to click on "Manage", however this "Manage" button/option no longer exists.  Is there any way to see usage data for an Azure CDN?  I would also like to have an idea of how much I'll be billed.

Here's the portal screen that I have (lacking the "Manage" option on the CDN Profile)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Manage" button/option exists on Azure CDN from **Verizon** provider, whereas your pricing tier is standard Microsoft. See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-real-time-stats).

For the billing structure for content hosted by Azure CDN, It is charged by a billing region, any HTTP(S) request that terminates at the CDN and some usage charges on the services used as the origin for your objects. You will get more details from [understanding Azure CDN billing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-billing) and [CDN pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cdn/) and [Pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/).

Comment: Thank you, that would explain it.  Is there any major difference between Azure CDN from Verizon and Azure CDN from Microsoft?  I've seen the big table showing the features of all three CDNs, but if one is much better than the Azure CDN from Microsoft then I would rather switch to another since they're all the same price

Comment: The Azure Premium Verizon CDN includes the [rules engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-verizon-premium-rules-engine) and advanced, real-time analytics features, also. it's more expensive for outbound data transfers than Azure CDN from Microsoft, refer to [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cdn/)